# Different results between ebean and manually entered SQL query?

Tags: playframework-2.1, ebean

I've built a MySQL query that returns 452 entries when I try it via phpMyAdmin, here's the query :

```
SELECT csp.id FROM child_subscription_prices csp 
JOIN child_moments cm ON csp.child_moment_id = cm.id 
JOIN moments m ON cm.moment_id = m.id 
JOIN poles p ON m.pole_id = p.id 
JOIN persons pr ON pr.id = csp.payer_id 
WHERE cm.day BETWEEN '2013-1-15' AND '2013-1-17' AND p.type_id IN (1,2,3) AND csp.center_id = 1 
ORDER BY pr.lastname ASC
```

But when I call it using Ebean (Play!Framework 2.1.1), like this :

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("y-M-d");
StringBuilder querySql = new StringBuilder();
querySql.append("SELECT csp.id FROM child_subscription_prices csp ");
querySql.append("JOIN child_moments cm ON csp.child_moment_id = cm.id ");
querySql.append("JOIN moments m ON cm.moment_id = m.id ");
querySql.append("JOIN poles p ON m.pole_id = p.id ");
querySql.append("JOIN persons pr ON pr.id = csp.payer_id ");
querySql.append("WHERE cm.day BETWEEN :start AND :end AND p.type_id IN (:poles) AND csp.center_id = :center ");
querySql.append("ORDER BY pr.lastname ASC;");       

SqlQuery query = Ebean.createSqlQuery(querySql.toString());
query.setParameter("start", format.format(start));
query.setParameter("end", format.format(end));
query.setParameter("poles", StringUtils.join(poleIds.toArray(), ","));
query.setParameter("center", Session.getCenter().getId());

List<SqlRow> rows = query.findList();
rows.size(); // Return 409 !!
```

Of course, I tested the parameter in Java and compared them, they are identical ! (I even updated my first query to match the dates (2013-01-15 => 2013-1-15, to be like the one made in Java!

I don't have any clue why I have 50 entries less using Java, is there a particular Ebean configuration that doesn't follow some related database for any reason, or something like this that would explain the differences ?

### Update

I also tried to count the number of results from the SQL query made in Java:

```
querySql.append("SELECT COUNT(csp.id) as total FROM child_subscription_prices csp ");
// ...

query.findUnique().getLong("total"); // Also 409 !
```

So it clearly seems to be a difference between the configuration in PhpMyAdmin and EBean, but I can't see which one!

Answer (score 0):

For information, the problem was coming from this line :

```
query.setParameter("poles", StringUtils.join(poleIds.toArray(), ","));
```

Instead, I just had to replace it to this :

```
// poleids is a List<Long>
query.setParameter("poles", poleIds);
```

And everything worked fine :)